# Golang: Right way to serve both http & https from Go web app with Goji?

Tags: https, go, goji

Is this the right way to for a single Go web app (using Goji) to handle both http and https traffic?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/graceful"
    "github.com/zenazn/goji/web"
)

func main() {
    r := web.New()
    //https://127.0.0.1:8000/r
    r.Get("/r", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", "r")
    })

    go graceful.ListenAndServeTLS(":8000", "cert.pem", "key.pem", r)

    r1 := web.New()
    //  http://127.0.0.1:8001/r1
    r1.Get("/r1", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", "r1")
    })

    graceful.ListenAndServe(":8001", r1)
}
```

Or what is the best method for having both ports 8000 and 8001 listened to by a single Go web app?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use nginx to terminate both HTTP and HTTPS (TLS) connections, reverse proxying them to a single Go server listening on (e.g.) port 8000. There's an example here you can leverage: https://gist.github.com/elithrar/77ee6746104b900e866c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new object, you can simply pass `r` to `graceful.ListenAndServe(":8001", r)`, unless of course you do a different action that depends on https.

Comment: Well in my case there would be some paths on which the SSL certificate is valid, and some on which it is not. So... what should I do about that?

Comment: what you're doing is fine then. you could define common functions somewhere and add them to your `r` and `r1`.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm just getting started with Go. And is it correct to have the first as a goroutine and the second not?

Comment: Yes since otherwise it would block, you might want to do `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` to use all processor cores for handling requests.

Comment: Interesting. Where do I use that?

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/_5q_uSYTpD usually the first line of main but anywhere in main should work.